# Палка для держания веревки с бельем

Tags: лексика

Не знаю, знакома ли вам реалия, вынесенная в заголовок, или нет, но у нас в Армении такая палка называлась то ли подстановкой, то ли постановкой. Но в словарях такого значения я не нашел. А как у вас называется такая палка, если, конечно, вам знакома такая реалия.

Comment: Мне мама говорила "Сынок, иди палку поставь".

Comment: Мама не говорила что перед прямой речью ставится?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У нас говорили просто "палка для белья".
Но "подстановкой" её действительно называли, и подходящая история у этого слова есть.
Цитата из сети:

> ...Веревки, на которых сушилось белье, подпирались специальными деревянными палками ("подстановкой") с разрезом на верхнем конце.

В старом издании словаря Даля в статье "нога" упоминается такое значение:

> Деревянная подстановка различного вида, заменяющая утраченную ногу.

[Здесь](https://gold_mining.academic.ru/749/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%29) это же слово упоминается уже в значении "подставка" в другом старом словаре.

Comment: Странно, что у этого слово это значение не зафиксиррвано ни одним современным словарем.

Answer (score 3):

Подстава — так называла "бельевую палку" моя бабушка (Новгород, 1909).
Это довольно-таки длинный, гладкий шест с фигурным крючком почти на самом конце.  Загогулина была сделана из крупного гвоздя и имела особую форму — чтобы веревка на ветру из него не выскакивала.
Точно так же она называла и палку (или шест) с небольшой перекладиной (для поддержки урожайных веток яблонь и слив).

Слово нашлось в толковом словаре Ефремовой:
[**подста́ва**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/218752), *ж. устар.*
1. Подставка, подпорка.

Answer (score 2):

Никакого другого названия, кроме палки, не припоминаю.

Comment: Промежуточная опора — стойка. Незнакомо?

Comment: В моем дворе палку для белья никто стойкой не называл.